# Как сделать "карусель категорий" как на Google Play?

Tags: html, css, django

Вот пример того что я хочу сделать. Нужно еще, чтобы если навбар был слишком длинным, то он листался как "карусель"

[image: Вот как-то так надо реализовать навбар на сайте]

Comment: Дать блоку `overflow-x: auto`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson А что это даст? Куда добавлять? В тег nav или в div? *погуглил, в диву все таки